# kmeans scatter plot: plot different colors per cluster

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, k-means

I am trying to do a scatter plot of a kmeans output which clusters sentences of the same topic together. The problem i am facing is plotting points that belongs to each cluster a certain color.

```
sentence_list=["Hi how are you", "Good morning" ...] #i have 10 setences
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++',n_init=10, verbose=1) 
#with 5 cluster, i want 5 different colors
km.fit(vectorized)
km.labels_ # [0,1,2,3,3,4,4,5,2,5]

pipeline = Pipeline([('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())])
X = pipeline.fit_transform(sentence_list).todense()
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(X)
data2D = pca.transform(X)
plt.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1])

km.fit(X)
centers2D = pca.transform(km.cluster_centers_)
plt.hold(True)
labels=np.array([km.labels_])
print labels
```

My problem is in the bottom code for **plt.scatter()**; what should i use for the parameter **c**?

1. when i use `c=labels` in the code, i get this error:

`number in rbg sequence outside 0-1 range`

2.When i set `c= km.labels_` instead, i get the error:

`ValueError: Color array must be two-dimensional`

```
plt.scatter(centers2D[:,0], centers2D[:,1], 
            marker='x', s=200, linewidths=3, c=labels)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `color=` or `c=` property should be a matplotlib color, as mentioned in the documentation for [`plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

To map a integer label to a color just do

```
LABEL_COLOR_MAP = {0 : 'r',
                   1 : 'k',
                   ....,
                   }

label_color = [LABEL_COLOR_MAP[l] for l in labels]
plt.scatter(x, y, c=label_color)
```

If you don't want to use the builtin one-character color names, you can use other color definitions. See the documentation on matplotlib colors.

Comment: Instead of manually typing in a color for each new cluster, how do we use **colormap** so that in case i change the cluster number in the future, i dont have to add in a new color again?

Comment: Or use the built in color maps in `mpl.colors`

Comment: @tcaswell That is an option. But I guess you 1) might want to have the mapping between label ID and color explicit, and 2) must know that your label IDs are not greater than the number of colors in the colormap.

Comment: you just need to scale them all between 0 and 1 for the continuous color maps.  If you have so many labels that you stop being able to resolve the difference on the continuous color maps, you have too many labels

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. Just wanted to point out potential pit falls :)

Comment: Thanks, @HannesOvrén for specifying the color names here. Found the other colors and color palettes on https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html. I required them for ease of coding

Answer (score 33):

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Scaling the data to normalize
model = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(X)

# Visualize it:
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=model.labels_.astype(float))
```

Now you have different color for different clusters.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Beauty! Weirdly, I can't getthe pandas shorthand to work for this case (i.e. using data.plot(...) throws a 'c=' too many color element error.

Comment: Bang.Great Trick.Thanks for that.

Comment: Does this guarantee unique colour per cluster no matter how big `n_cluster` is?

Comment: Where does data come from in your answer? Did you mean X? Even if it is X, how do you know X's shape is (n, 2)?

Comment: Works ok - for me it sets the colours as along a greyscale between white and black. Meaning one cluster appears as white and isn't visible. It can also be hard to distinguish between different types of grey.

Answer (score 3):

It should work:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans;
cluster = KMeans(10);
cluster.fit(M);

cluster.labels_;

plt.scatter(M[:,0],M[:,1], c=[matplotlib.cm.spectral(float(i) /10) for i in cluster.labels_]);
```

Comment: I like the idea, but semicolons in Python?

Comment: Using semicolons is a pythonic way of obtaining columns or rows. Here is getting the first column with all the rows (a column vector) and the second column respectively.